# Sending an email using VBA and IBM Lotus Notes

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I know about topics dealing with similar problem but none of them solves directly my problem (or at least I don't see it). I am using following code:

```
Sub SendEmailUsingCOM()

'*******************************************************************************************
' Unlike OLE automation, one can use Early Binding while using COM
' To do so, replace the generic "object" by "commented" UDT
' Set reference to: Lotus Domino Objects
'*******************************************************************************************
Dim nSess       As Object 'NotesSession
Dim nDir        As Object 'NotesDbDirectory
Dim nDb         As Object 'NotesDatabase
Dim nDoc        As Object 'NotesDocument
Dim nAtt        As Object 'NotesRichTextItem
Dim vToList     As Variant, vCCList As Variant, vBody As Variant
Dim vbAtt       As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim sFilPath    As String
Dim sPwd        As String

'*******************************************************************************************
'To create notesession using COM objects, you can do so by using.
'either ProgID  = Lotus.NotesSession
'or     ClsID   = {29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}
'Replace ProgID by the commented string below.
'*******************************************************************************************
Set nSess = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 'New:{29131539-2EED-1069-BF5D-00DD011186B7}

'*******************************************************************************************
'This part initializes the session and creates a new mail document
'*******************************************************************************************
sPwd = Application.InputBox("Type your Lotus Notes password!", Type:=2)
Call nSess.Initialize(sPwd)
Set nDir = nSess.GetDbDirectory("")
Set nDb = nDir.OpenMailDatabase
Set nDoc = nDb.CreateDocument

'*******************************************************************************************
'If you want to send it to multiple recipients then use variant array to get the names from
'the specified range as below
'Add / Remove Comment mark from vCCList as per your needs.
'*******************************************************************************************
vToList = Application.Transpose(Range("A1").Resize(Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)
vCCList = Application.Transpose(Range("B1").Resize(Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value)

'*******************************************************************************************
'If you want to send it to multiple recipients then use variant array to get the names from
'the specified range as below
'Add / Remove Comment mark from vCCList as per your needs.
'*******************************************************************************************
With nDoc

    Set nAtt = .CreateRichTextItem("Body")
    Call .ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo")
    Call .ReplaceItemValue("Subject", "Test Lotus Notes Email using COM")

    With nAtt
        .AppendText (Range("C2").Value)

       'Decide if you want to attach a file.
        vbAtt = MsgBox("Do you want to attach document?", vbYesNo, "Attach Document")

            Select Case vbAtt
            Case 6
                .AddNewLine
                .AppendText ("********************************************************************")
                .AddNewLine
                sFilPath = Application.GetOpenFilename
                Call .EmbedObject(1454, "", sFilPath) '1454 = Constant for EMBED_ATTACHMENT
            Case 7
                'Do Nothing
            End Select

    End With

    Call .ReplaceItemValue("CopyTo", vCCList)
    Call .ReplaceItemValue("PostedDate", Now())
    Call .Send(False, vToList)

End With

End Sub
```

The code stops at **Set nSess = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")** saying **Run-time error 429: ActiveX component can't create object**

I saw some discussions about missing nnotes.dll but when I try to add it using Tools>References> and browse to the nnotes.dll file, it says "Can't add a reference to the specified file"
For sure I miss some basic knowledge, but I would just love to make it work and send specific ranges in excel via email. 
Do you know, ideally step by step, what I should do?

Comment: I may have gone a step further when changing Set nSess = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") to Set nSess = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession"), but then after typing the password I get stuck at Call nSess.Initialize(sPwd) with a debug message "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: You can't just add nnotes.dll as a reference. The classes must be registered. Notes.NotesSessoin is an OLE class and it does not support that method. Lotus.NotesSession is a COM class, and it does support that method. The OLE classes require that the Notes client is running. It will start it if it is not running. The client itself must request the password. The COM classes only require that the Notes client (or Domino server) is installed and configured. It does not have to be running. How are you executing your VBA? Which Microsoft app?  Which version, and is it 32-bit or 64 bit.